# Oracle PL/sql : Calculate sum of all possible number combinations

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Oracle database

Let's say I have 3 boxes with different quantity of items inside (no of box is fixed )

Box id's and qtys below

```
B101 5
B102 5
B103 4
```

There is a container existing with some quantity of item inside

Existing qty - 2

Capacity of container- 15

Now I want all possible sum of combinations of box1,box2,box3, existing qty.

I will select only the combination where sum < capacity best possible fit

All combination must have the existing qty mandatory as we cannot ignore that

End result for this case

Box 1 + box 2 + existing qty .5+5+2 which fits within capacity 15 .

Need a PL/SQL block to perform the same activity

I will fetch the box id's and box qtys in  a table of records (user-defined )

Comment: This problem seems to be closely related to the knapsack problem. If you have N boxes, the total number of possible combinations appears to be 2^N, which can quickly get out of hand (eg : With juste 16 boxes, you already have 65 536 possible combinations). Do you have an idea of the maximum number of different boxes? See also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be easier ways, but I would use a recursive CTE. Here's a plain SQL example, with extra sample rows:

```
create table boxes (id varchar2(4), qty number);

insert into boxes values ('B101',5);
insert into boxes values ('B102',5);
insert into boxes values ('B103',4);
insert into boxes values ('B104',9);
insert into boxes values ('B105',11);
insert into boxes values ('B106',2);
insert into boxes values ('B107',1);

with c (r, id, qty, lvl) as (
    -- anchor query
    select id as r, id, qty, 1 as lvl
    from boxes
    where qty + 2 < 15
    union all
    -- recursive query
    select c.r || ',' || b.id, b.id, b.qty+c.qty, c.lvl+1
    from boxes b
    join c on c.id < b.id
    where b.qty + c.qty + 2 < 15
    )
select r, lvl, qty 
from c
order by qty desc, lvl asc
;
```

This will show all the combinations, with the best fit at the top. I added a secondary sort on the level, assuming that in the case of a tie, you'd prefer the fewest number of boxes per container. But you might prefer maximum boxes per container instead.

I also used `join on c.id < b.id` instead of a cross join because I think you don't really want ALL combinations, you want all UNIQUE combinations, so it's more of a tree search.

And an example as a PL/SQL function:

```
create or replace function fit_boxes(existing_qty in number, capacity in number)
return varchar2
is
    box_list varchar2(4000);
begin

    with c (r, id, qty, lvl) as (
        select id as r, id, qty, 1 as lvl
        from boxes
        where qty + existing_qty < capacity
        union all
        select c.r || ',' || b.id, b.id, b.qty+c.qty, c.lvl+1
        from boxes b
        join c on c.id < b.id
        where b.qty + c.qty + existing_qty < capacity
        )
    select r into box_list
    from c
    order by qty desc, lvl asc
    fetch first 1 row only
    ;

    return box_list;

exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
  return 'No boxes fit'
end;
/

select fit_boxes(2,15) from dual;
```

Finally, I would have guessed that you wanted sum <= capacity, but your question definitely says "sum < capacity", so that's how I wrote it. Just test it out with your data and make sure it works as expected.

Edit: Sure, to explain the query logic - for a **recursive CTE**, you start with an anchor query and union it to a recursive query (which keeps iteratively selecting from the CTE itself).

For the anchor, we start by selecting all the single boxes which can fit in the container (where qty + 2 < 15). In our example, they all fit, so we have 7 rows with a lvl of 1.

For the recursive part, we already have 1 or more boxes in the container `c`, and we want to see which remaining boxes from `b` will fit. So we join them, using `c.id < b.id` to make sure that we're only looking at the boxes in `b` which aren't already in `c`. And once we've looked at all the boxes, the join will return 0 rows and the recursion will stop.

For the 4 columns in the CTE - `r` displays all the boxes that we've added to the container so far, `id` shows the id of the most recently added box (important so we can keep track of which boxes we've considered), `qty` sums up the size of all the boxes currently in the container, and `lvl` shows how many boxes are in the container.

Comment: This works great. I have my box id's and qtys saved in a bulk collect variable (which is a table of records ) when I'm using it directly in select statement instead of table name I'm getting error. How to do union or self join of bulk collect variables?

Comment: I created the types in schema instead of inside package and the above issue got resolved. Can you also explain the working of your code ?

Comment: Ok, I updated it with some explanation. Recursive CTEs / hierarchical queries can be pretty confusing.